# No Internet Access In Docker Container When Connected to Cisco AnyConnect VPN

Tags: linux, docker, centos, vpn, cisco

I am connected to a corporate VPN and need to be able to run docker containers while the VPN is connected due to the fact that the container needs to be able to access corporate endpoints. However, when I am connected with AnyConnect VPN, docker has no internet access at all. Neither to our corporate endpoints or the internet.

I am running CentOS7 as my host operating system.

A simple way to reproduce this issue is to install a minimal linux distro, install AnyConnect VPN, connect to vpn and try to run the following docker container:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container I try to ping google dns

```
[###]$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

There will be no response. If I disconnect from AnyConnect VPN and retry the above, I get a ping response.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This issue only occurs with Cisco AnyConnect. When connected to a VPN with different VPN software I don't have the issue, but I'm forced to use AnyConnect for work.

Answer (score 4):

After you make a change to the network interfaces, you often need to restart the docker engine to rebuild all of the routes and iptables entries. With Linux and systemd, use:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Still no network after restarting docker. If you follow the example above I'd bet you would also not have a network connection after restarting docker.

Comment: This issue seems specific to Cisco AnyConnect as I don't have the issue when I test with a different VPN. I'm looking for a work around with a focus on AnyConnect as I HAVE to use that for work.

Comment: This work for me, I was using AWS VPN client

Comment: I just disabled IPv6 on my main LAN, then the network connection in docker stopped working, even after a system restart. Just manually restarting docker only really did the trick. A system restart probably doesn't trigger the necessary rebuild. Thanks!

Comment: worked for me, after using a VPN

Answer (score 1):

Ping outside and internet access are different. You could access internet but could not ping as limit by your corporation network. I suggest running busybox

```
docker run -it --rm busybox
```

and check the dns setup inside

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

From there you may see list of nameserver ip addresses. Now you could try to ping those to make sure they are reachable from inside. If not, you could try

```
traceroute 1.2.3.4
```

to see how far you could go from inside container, the first 2 lines should be ip of docker and the host machine, and then the ip of your corporation network

```
1  172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1)  0.016 ms  0.011 ms  0.009 ms
2  10.1.249.4 (10.1.249.4)  38.487 ms  35.697 ms  35.558 ms
```

Usually it's problem of the nameserver generated inside /etc/resolv.conf
file. If it's the case, then you need to check /etc/resolv.conf
in the host machine and update the docker setup to generate the nameservers correctly inside container.

Comment: Hello I only see the first line on traceroute. This probably means my host is not forwarding the packets via NAT MASQUERADE ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `openconnect` instead of CISCO AnyConnect solved the issue for me.

check https://www.sitecoregabe.com/2021/05/cisco-anyconnect-docker-networking-issues.html